# Vitae Awesome CV cover letter

Tags: awesome-cv

I'm using RStudio v1.4 "Juliet Rose" and I have written my CV with 'Awesome-CV' but I don't know how to access the cover letter function.

Can anyone help, please? - I'm still quite new to R...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the cover letter there is an example on https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/examples/coverletter.tex. There it is a document that is separate from the CV itself (using the same documentclass, but with different commands and environments), I'm not sure if it is possible to create one document with the CV and cover letter together.

Comment: Marijn - thank you. I will look into it further - I have those examples but cannot 'compile PDF' with either of them. Originally I opened a new RMarkdown template with the Awesome-CV [vitae] and formatted it through compiling an additional R-script with my personal info, as suggested. 
I'm now thinking to re-write the coverletter.tex file to suit my own criteria (personal info/letter info/letter content) and compile to pdf. Is that the usual way?

Comment: The usual way is not to go through RMarkdown but to compile `.tex` files directly by LaTeX itself - this gives you _much_ more flexibility and control over the document (and more informative error messages).

Comment: Thanks again Marijn, I think I've got it! Finally!

Opened the awesome-cover.tex file straight from an ordinary folder and edited from there, via TEXworks. All good running through xelatex and MIKtex (I think).

Every day is a learning day, obviously it's quite simple to replace the original text with what you want/need. Thanks again for your help - this has been a really interesting exercise!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered an easy workaround to formatting the cover letter. If you add a formatting command in the Markdown file itself, it seems to override the headings/subheadings formatting from the awesome-cv.cls. I used

```
\vskip 1cm
\hfill 20 February 2024\break
\vskip 0.5cm
To Whom It May Concern
```

This results in a right-justified date (you could also use the R `sys.date()`) followed by "To Whom It May Concern".
[image]
You can adjust the values of `\vskip` or remove the `\hfill` and `\break` for a left-justified date or maybe the company address. This way you can keep the same header as the awesome-cv and not worry about subheadings or sections.